# Coordinates remain very high when converting projections

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson

I have [this GeoJSON file](https://ckan.dataplatform.nl/dataset/c1059cef-be66-4a7a-9657-2f38f55794ed/resource/a175afe5-67e2-4e45-8b71-62f30377bf7d/download/wijken.json) which uses the following projection: EPSG:28992. I want to convert this to EPSG:3857 but I don't have GIS software available. I have tried [ogre](https://ogre.adc4gis.com/), but when I first convert it to a shapefile and then back to GeoJSON using the aforementioned projections, it still shows coordinates with extremely high numbers (476628.5890141478,6820821.561640609 etc). The same applies when I try converting it using [reproject](https://github.com/perliedman/reproject).

In both cases when I try loading the converted files into [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/) it fails -- it doesn't show on the map. In EPSG:3857, I'm expecting something like 4.30, 52.08 instead of coordinates that are in the hundreds of thousands.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how to get the right values?

Comment: Might be an obvious question, but what is keeping you from downloading and using QGis?

Comment: With EPSG:3857 you must expect coordinate values in range `-20026376.39 -20048966.10 - 20026376.39 20048966.10` http://epsg.io/3857

Comment: [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) has coordinates in meters, so high numbers (476628.5890141478,6820821.561640609 etc) are expected. If you want coordinates in decimal degrees (i.e longitude and latitude), reproject to [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326).

Comment: Wait.. I'm quite confused, in Leaflet I was under the impression that I must use EPSG 3857 but in the examples I see decimal degrees being used. I guess this is another question in itself. I will post this separately.

Comment: The geojson files generally should be in WGS84 (EPSG:4326). If I am not mistaken, by default, leaflet expects that and will reproject the data internally to EPSG:3857

Comment: Thanks! I have posted another question about this issue because I was using the Leaflet docs where they say EPSG:3857 is the default. But that is another topic. At least this is cleared up!

Comment: @FSimardGIS GeoJSON should be in CRS:84 (lon/lat coordinates) that's not the same as EPSG:4326 (lat/lon coordinates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to reproject your file to EPSG:4326 (latitudes and longitudes) if you want to see it in geojson.io.

EPSG:3857 is not a coordinate system that uses longitudes and latitudes. It is a projected coordinate system using meters as units. Coordinates in EPSG:3857 can go up to about 20,000,000.

Comment: epsg:4326 is lat/lon, not lon/lat see the EPSG registry ~ http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326

Comment: @nmtoken You're right, thanks for mentioning this. For the sake of the coordinate conversion, I think it does the trick for the OP's needs, but indeed, as you say, technically 4326 is lat,lon, and geojson should be in CRS:84 (lon, lat) revesed axis order from the 4326 definition.

Comment: Quick question: if you use a program like ArchGIS and you select EPSG:4326, will it be compatible with geojson? Or is it a problem that lat/lon are in reverse? If so, what setting is required in this kind of program when exporting the dataset?

Comment: ArcGIS handles the conversion correctly, it writes x first (longitude), then y (latitude) in the geojson file, from a dataset in WGS84. So it writes the coordinates to respect the format output, same principle as, for example, for KML files as well.